# Guide for Deploying Lightning Applications?

Tags: deployment, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there an official guide for deploying lightning components/applications? I have a component I want to use in another salesforce organization. So far I've tried creating a managed package (as recommended in these two links: [link 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_packaging.htm) and [link 2](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf)), but ultimately I don't see my components in my destination organization.

To clarify, I do see my package as being installed:
[image]

However I do not see my component listed on the Mobile Navigation page:
[image]

Which is where I expect to see it, since it shows up on that page on the original organization I developed the component for.

Comment: Is the component marked implements="force:appHostable"? The appHostable interface makes the component available on the Navigation Menu Items list. See [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I am including `implements="force:appHostable"` in the aura:component tag. I should also mention that I do see the components in the target organization's developer console too. Not sure what other steps I need to integrate the component in Salesforce1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a Lightning Tab for the component? Just having the component in the org is not enough to have it in Salesforce1.

Go to Setup > Create > Tabs, and scroll down to Lightning Tabs. Create a new one for your component, and give it a name and style. *Then* try to add the tab to mobile navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that you have not marked your component(s) as access="global". Just like Visualforce and Apex in order to share/publish namespaced components/events/interfaces/applications/attributes/etc they need to be marked access="global"

Comment: I had not done this at first, thanks for the heads up. Looks like there's also information here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_intro.htm